# Is it possible to change an icon from a non-shorcut file?

Tags: icons

It's easy to change the icon of a shortcut file but it's possible to change the icon of a program file (e.g .exe) on Windows Xp?

Comment: On a Mac, changing icons *might* invalidate the software's code signing signature, which (in the future?) *might* prevent network access or software updates. At least, that is what some tried to scare me with but I've not seen problems yet. Chealion once pointed out that a broken signature on the Mac's Keychain Access application will stop access to stored secrets; http://superuser.com/questions/47504/if-mac-code-signing-is-tampered-with-what-might-fail/72264#72264

Answer (score 1):

Sure. There are tools on the web called Resource Editors with which you can edit icons, dialog boxes and strings in an exe file. Try 'Resource Hacker' in google :)

note: before changing files with ResHack, always create a backup of the original.

Comment: +1, but bear in mind some applications won't like it, and any updates will likely revert your changes.

Comment: But you can not change every .exe's icon because most of them are locked.