# "accept incoming network connections" dialog flashes

Tags: macos, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the Mac OS X firewall dialog recurringly pop-up and disappear by itself (without letting me respond) under Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/100013/why-does-the-mac-os-x-firewall-dialog-recurringly-pop-up-and-disappear-by-itself)

Almost every time I open the "open" or "save" dialog on my mac, for example in TextEdit, a dialog flashes very quickly. I had to take a screenshot to be able to read it. It says:

```
Do you want the application
"Smultron.app" to accept incoming
network connections?
[Deny] [Allow]
```

I don't understand why my text editor would want to accept incoming network connections (other than the fact that there are some shared drives on the network). This dialog seems very odd.

- How do I know whether this is a virus, and
- How can I get rid of this dialog?

Just in case, my firewall is turned on and has a list of exceptions (which doesn't include textedit or smultron).

edit: This seems to be the same problem as [How to get rid of annoying and quickly disappearing firewall popups on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/176446/how-to-get-rid-of-annoying-and-quickly-disappearing-firewall-popups-on-mac) and [Why does the Mac OS X firewall dialog recurringly pop-up and disappear by itself (without letting me respond) under Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/100013/why-does-the-mac-os-x-firewall-dialog-recurringly-pop-up-and-disappear-by-itself). I'd vote them up if I could.

Comment: I am voting to close, but as you cannot comment yet on other questions, some questions here: any change you changed the icon (or other package contents) of TextEdit or Smultron? And: does it really say Smultron when using TextEdit?