# Google Chrome constantly asking for Keychain permission?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, keychain

My Google Chrome installation on Snow Leopard is asking for access to the keychain any time I go to a site with login information... This happened really suddenly - I've restarted and tried different combinations of settings (always allow) to no avail. The suggestions here: [Safari keeps asking permission to access the keychain](https://superuser.com/questions/30006/safari-keeps-asking-permission-to-access-the-keychain) have not solved my problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google screwed up the application signing in their update procedure. I'm just randomly guess they switched the OS X binary over to something like what they were doing with the Windows version (a decompiling, then patching procedure, then recompiling) without considering the possibility of differing hashes.

> Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard includes a new
>   code signing security feature that
>   helps verify the integrity of an
>   application. Applications are signed
>   by their creators before being
>   distributed using their private key,
>   and then can be verified on the
>   customer’s machine using the company’s
>   public key.
>
> Mac OS X’s Keychain
>   Services leverage this new code
>   signing feature to verify the
>   signature of each application before
>   allowing access to the contents of the
>   keychain. By verifying the signature,
>   the Mac OS X keychain Services can
>   detect when a potentially malicious
>   change has been made to an application
>   and thereby protect your sensitive
>   data by denying the changed
>   application access.
>
> src: http://help.agile.ws/1Password3/invalid_code_signature.html

As for the fix? Not quite sure. I've just been hammering on Always Allow. I still get them sometimes but ever since I've started hammering, I've been getting less. Eventually, it'll go away if you keep doing that.

Hey, looking back at my guess, try reinstalling.

Comment: this is happening to me again, a year later.  boo Google :(

Comment: [one year later] - Is this some kind of Groundhog Day? From A to Z, I had to click `Always Allow` for all the stored sites...

Answer (score 18):

This is what worked for me. Apple Snow Leopard and Google Chrome 17.0.963.56.

1. Quit Chrome
2. Open Utilities: Keychain Access
3. Search for Chrome
4. Delete "Chrome Safe Storage"
5. Start up Chrome. Note that Chrome Safe Storage is back in the list.
6. Go to a site which requires a password stored in the Keychain. The Keychain dialog box will pop up and ask for your password. Type the password (like you normally do).

Comment: Worked!  Looked like my sync now isn't working but I will research that..

Comment: My problem wasn't that it asked for passwords for new sites but that I had to click through a whole bunch of "do you want to..." when starting Chrome. Solution was to delete the entry in Keychain access and then restart Chrome. I have to reenter all passwords now but that is only fair - if I tell my users to do it I should be able to do it myself too.

Comment: If I quit chrome how do I read these instructions?

Answer (score 3):

Re-installing fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me is moving the Google Chrome keychain entry from a secondary keychain into my primary keychain. I have multiple keychains due to poorly moving my keychain database from system to system and moving it into the "master", or "primary", database fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Keychain Access menu, try to run Keychain First Aid, it ask password and select Verify and start. If found error, try it again and select Repair.

Comment: No errors were found.

Answer (score 1):

The fix to both Google Chrome and Chromium should be rolling out this week:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108238#c61

...and there was much rejoicing!

Comment: Nope, 1 year later and still happening.

Answer (score 1):

This [might be caused by Chrome trying to access credentials saved by Safari](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/04/google-chrome-wants-to-use-your-confidential-information-store-in-the-keychain/). The solution in a short version:

1. Go to Keychain Access
2. Delete the entry "facebook.com (password not saved)" or something similar (in my computer it appears with a blue icon)
3. Done